# How to implement ReST services with Sails.js?

Tags: rest, websocket, sails.js

I am quite new to Node. I came across [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/). I think it is based on WebSocket, which seems to be really good for building real-time applications. I would like to know that whether Sails can be used to implement REST architecture as it uses WebSocket? And if yes, how?

Comment: ReST has a hypermedia constraint though. So the simple example, and out of the box sails set up does not address this constraint, so technically this is not ReSTful. This example illustrates ReSTlike resource orientation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it can. Sails JS allows you to easily build a RESTful API, essentially with no effort to get started. Also, websockets (through socket.io) are integrated by default into the view and api.

To create a fully RESTful app from the ground up, it actually requires no JS. Try:

```
sails new testapp
cd testapp
sails generate model user
sails generate controller user
cd <main root>
sails lift
```

The CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delete) actions are already created for you. No code!

You can create a user in your browser by doing the following:
HTTP POST (using a tool like PostMan) to http://:1337/user/create

{
        "firstName": "Bob",
        "lastName": "Jones"
}

Next, do a GET to see the new user:
HTTP GET http://:1337/user/

FYI - Sails JS uses a default disk based database to get you going

Done.

Answer (score 0):

```
sails new testapp

cd testapp

sails generate api apiName
```

controller

```
create: function (req, res) {
        var payload = {
          name:req.body.name,
          price:req.body.price,
          category:req.body.category,
          author:req.body.author,
          description:req.body.description
        };
       Book.create(payload).exec(function(err){
          if(err){
            res.status(500).json({'error':'something is not right'})
          }else{
            res.status(200).json({'success':true, 'result':payload, 'message':'Book Created success'})
          }
       });
   },

   readone: async function (req, res) {
        var id = req.params.id;
        var fff = await Book.find(id);
           if(fff.length == 0){
             res.status(500).json({'error':'No record found from this ID'})
           }else{
             res.status(200).json({'success':true, 'result':fff, 'message':'Record found'})
           }
    },
```

model

```
 attributes: {
    id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true },
    name: { type: 'string', required: true, },
    price: { type: 'number', required: true, },
    category: { type: 'string', required: true, },
    author: { type: 'string' },
    description: { type: 'string' },
  },
```

routes

```
'post /newbook': 'BookController.create',
  'get /book/:id': 'BookController.readone',
```